# Javascript - do something every x number of iterations in loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, for-loop

I'm using the Google Maps API which has a limit of 10 requests per second. I want to have a short delay every 10 requests.

```
for (var i = 0; i < myRequests.length; i++) {
   // pause every 10 iterations 
}
```

My maths aren't sharp... How can I know whenever I reach 10 iterations in order to do something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(function loop(z) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        //use myRequests[z] 
        console.log(myRequests[z]);
        z++;
        if(z===myRequests.length)
            return;
    }
    setTimeout(function(){loop(z)},1000);
})(0);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/S5BLZ/)

Comment: Very interesting approach! Will this use a lot of the CPU resources or freeze other javascript?

Comment: this depend on which code you use inside the loop. If your code make some async calls, i don't think you will notice anything on the UI side.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array that stores the requests and use this:

```
    var index = -1;
    for(var i=0; i<anArray.length; i++){
        if(anArray[i]!=false){
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(index!=-1){
        function makeCall(){
            //api calls
            anArray[index] = true;
         }
    }else{   
        setTimeout(makeCall, 1000)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

### Loops can't wait

The only way to "wait" is to use a timeout, unfortunately for this situation timeouts are asynchronous, so they are useless in a loop because the loop will continue on anyway.

Instead, you will need to use a recursive function.

### The math part

We can save a bunch of logic by using the modulo operator (`%`) to get the remainder of the currently incremented count divided by the split that you want to wait at. If the remainder is 0 (the current count is a multiple of the split), wait the requested amount of time.

### Example

```js
function log(out) { document.body.innerHTML += out; }

function repeat(count, split, limit, wait) {
    var args = arguments;
    if(++count <= limit) {
        log([count, '0' + count][+(count < 10)] + ', ');
        if(!(count % split) && count < limit) {
            log('wait<br>');
            setTimeout(function(){
                repeat.apply(null, args);
            }, wait);
        } else repeat.apply(null, args);
    } else log('done');
}

repeat(0, 10, 50, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the modulus to determine, if you're in the 10th iteration.

```
for (var i = 0; i < myRequests.length; i++) {
  // pause every 10 iterations 
  if (i%10==0){
    sleep(5000)  
  }
}
```